# I am trying to calculate the specific heat of an unknown object through an experiment; why am I getting a negative value?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

I am doing a Physics lab where I have to determine the specific heat of an unknown object (50 g).

The lab is basically composed of two parts:

1. A calorimeter is filled with 500 mL of water and is connected to a current supplier. The rising temperature (degrees C) of the water is measured, which is then graphed according to time (s). The graph is linear.

   Using power (P = VI), the slope of the graph (dT/dt), the specific heat of water (c_water = 4.182j/gC), and the mass of the water (m), the heat capacity of the calorimeter (C) is calculated.

   I used the following formula:

> P=(c_water * m+C)dT/dt

2. Again, the calorimeter is filled with 500 mL of water and is connected to a current supplier. The unknown object (50 g) is placed in the water. Then, rising temperature (degrees C) of the water is measured, which is then graphed according to time (s). The graph is linear.

   Using the heat capacity of the calorimeter (C) obtained in the previous part, the specific heat of the unknown object (c_uk) is calculated.

   I used the following formula:

> P−P_loss=(c_water * m+c_uk * m_uk+C)dT/dt

, where P_loss was −0.912J⋅s^−1.

I keep getting a negative value for the specific heat of the unknown object (c_uk). (something like -0.243)

Am I using the wrong formula? If not, what could be a factor that is causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second equation has a wrong sign. The general formula is

\begin{align}
\sum_i P_i = \left( \sum_i c_i m_i + C \right) \frac{dT}{dt}.
\end{align}

Your expression has a minus sign for $P_{loss}$ that shouldn't be there. After this is changed, you should get a positive value for $P_{loss}$.